# How to add php code in href attribute in wp page content?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in `php` and i need your guide and one think I want to tell you I am also using local host server on window 7.
How to write the php code inside `href` such as when we transfer the files of my site then This code takes automatic domain name with page name in the `url` when visiting the link of any page.
This is my code in the content of page in the WordPress.

```
<img class="size-full img-responsive img-circle wp-image-165 aligncenter" 
    src="http://localhost/doctors/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/dnatesting.jpg" 
    alt="" width="493" height="335" />
    <div class="caption">
     <h4 style="text-align: center;"><a href="[insert_php] echo esc_url(home_url( '/list of specialities' ) ); [/insert_php] ">read more</a> 
 </h4>
   &nbsp;
```

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough, what the final result of your desired url ? what do you mean by dynamic permalink and where this link goes to a page ? or a post ? or somewhere else ?

Comment: this link goes to the ' list of specialities' pages and this pages assigned with a custom template_name in wordpress,

Comment: here dynamic permalink means when we transfer the files from local server to any other server it takes automatic particular path of that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way how to do it:

```
<a href="<?= esc_url(home_url( '/list of specialities' ) ); ?>">read more</a>
```

**Edit:**
If you are trying to insert this code into the Wordpress editor, it will not work, because Wordpress will not execute PHP per default. In this case, either install a plugin that will allow you to execute PHP or simply use [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Comment: sir i did installed the insert php plugin to allow to use the php code as a short code whenever not working ,have any possibilities for it plz tell me?

Comment: I guess you are using the plugin "Insert PHP". I have tested your code and it works for me. Do you get an error? Btw. you should replace the spaces in `/list of specialities`.

Comment: sir after replacing as you instruct me whenever not working but i am getting at address bar this http://localhost/doctors/[insert_php]%20echo%20esc_url(%20home_url(%20'/list-of-specialities/'%20)%20);%20[/insert_php]

Comment: sir it's working but for when i am not assigning the templates to page ,when assigning the templates to page its not working,i want when we assign template to pages it work, sir please try can it is possible?.

Comment: sir getting same result as home_url(),

Comment: getting this result in address bar http://localhost/doctors/[insert_php]%20echo%20esc_url(network_home_url('/list-of-specialities'));[/insert_php]

Comment: That should work. Did you activate the plugin Insert PHP?